# apt-get working with organization network but now with home network (Ubuntu guest Virtual Box)

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am using cntlm to get apt-get working. This works fine when I am connected to my organization's network but I am unable to get this working with my home network. The apt-conf file contains:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://127.0.0.1:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://127.0.0.1:3128/";
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` and move all the contents there to a text file in some place so that apt.conf contains nothing. now your apt-get will fetch in home network. if you want to work in the previous proxy, restore the lines from the text file you have created. these are exactly the proxy configuration for apt.

Comment: Do I need to re-run the cntlm then after removing the contents of apt-get file?

Comment: not needed, you have to save the file /etc/apt/apt.conf in text editor  to make the changes. then run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: It doesn't work. Says failed to fetch and could not resolve.

Comment: can you access internet in ubuntu?

Comment: When I am connected to my organization network I can. Not when I am connected to home network.

Comment: go to all settings->network->network proxy. choose method 'none' and apply system-wide.

Comment: I did this. I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: you are working in VirtualBox right? see whether on virtualbox network settings you are attached to internal network

Comment: I was connected to NAT. But when I connected to Internal Network it still doesn't work.

Comment: means you have access to internet in host and not in guest with this settings?

Comment: try restarting your ubuntu virtual machine. what is your host machine os?

Comment: I have access in host. I restarted the VM. But nothing happened. Host is Windows.

Comment: what does the file  /etc/cntlm.conf contains, see this by`gedit  /etc/cntlm.conf`